# What is the right way to import Faker JS?

Tags: node.js, faker.js

I see that when importing [Faker JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker) into my NodeJS project and then build it, it bundles the whole module inside it. I just want to bundle a specific module inside it. Is it possible?

I, for example, use only the `faker.finance.currencyName()` function. I tried importing just `import "faker/lib/finance"` but that doesn't seem to work. The dist bundle is a whopping 824.67kb (when doing `npm run build` in vite-js).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what is exported, it does not appear that specific sub-modules can be imported.

- https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/blob/master/index.js#L4
- https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/blob/master/lib/index.js#L177

Comment: Thanks for this. This is unfortunate. I think I will create an issue to provide specific sub-modules in the export.

Comment: repo doesnt exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

@Manny is correct but the links are dead. After the FakerJS move something like this would work (TypeScript syntax)

```
import { name } from '@faker-js/faker';

const firstName = name.firstName();
```

or

```
import { 
  name as fakerName, 
  address as fakerAddress, 
  phone as fakerPhone
} from '@faker-js/faker';

const testUser = {
  firstName: fakerName.firstName(),
  lastName: fakerName.lastName(),
  phoneNumber: fakerPhone.phoneNumber(),
  city: fakerAddress.city()
};
```